# Verilog Implementation error DFFs and Gates

Tags: verilog

I am a beginner in verilog and came across this question-

Given the finite state machine circuit as shown, assume that the D flip-flops are initially reset to zero before the machine begins.

Build this circuit. 
[image]

My Code is -

```
module top_module (
input clk,
input x,
output z
); 
reg q,q1,q2;
always @(posedge clk)
    begin

        q<= q^x;
        q1<= ~q1 && x;
        q2<= ~q2 || x;
        z=~(q | q1 | q2);
    end 
 endmodule
```

Suggest me where i am going wrong!

Comment: Welcome! You haven't said what's failed, but try moving `z=...` outside the `always` block and change it to `assign z = ~(q | q1 | q2);`

Comment: It previously showed 43 mismatches but now its working fine. Could you please tell me the reason behind this?

Comment: Briefly, you were mixing combinatorial (continuous) assignment (`z=...`) and sequential logic (`q<=...`) in an edge sensitive `always` block. Continous assignments are either done using `assign`, or in an `always @*` (Verilog) or `always_comb` (SystemVerilog) construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the diagram, `z` is driven by a combinational logic. In the code, you are trying to drive `z` using sequential logic inside clockedge. You have to either use `z` as a `wire` and drive it using `assign` statement. Or use `z` as a `reg` and drive it inside `always@*` block.

General coding guideline is to not mix blocking and non-blocking assignments in the same `always` block.